# How to check the speed/problems of network-manager?

Tags: network-manager, configuration, performance

in between *suspend* and *awake* my system of course drops its wlan connection. Then once awakend from its suspend `notwork-manager` tries to reestablish the connection. All works fine , I think

BUT: doing the same on my dual-boot win-8 system is so much faster (wlan + with it internet is there instantly <1sec) on my Ubunut it takes 10+ seconds or more.

What could be a way to check for problems in network-mangager?
or any other way to "bring it to speed" (it must be possible, as even win8 does it!)

### update

looking for the gap in `/var/log/syslog` I can see already a "huge" (at least annoying 4 sec time gap in between (see yourself):

```
Mar 18 08:52:22 freak NetworkManager[1428]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 18 08:52:26 freak wpa_supplicant[1717]: Trying to authenticate with c0:25:06:c6:b4:fe (SSID='mywlan_essid' freq=2472 MHz)
```

who is so slow?

Comment: Alternatively, anybody knows a good tutorial to use cmdline tools to setup wlan easily/ automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I experience exactly the same issue, although my gap is 10 seconds long.

```
Sep 12 13:38:28 jumbo NetworkManager[1139]: <info> (wlan2): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 12 13:38:38 jumbo wpa_supplicant[1715]: wlan2: Trying to associate with 00:15:c7:29:86:81 (SSID='MILANO' freq=2412 MHz)
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any docs about the different interface states, so I can only guess what the "scanning" state means: Your computer listens for other Access Points with the same SSID and connects to the AP with the best signal quality.

Therefore, I believe this issue could be solved, if we would be able to set a static entry and hereby controll to which AP your computer should connect, this at least would be a solution for your workplace / home etc... As far as I know, nmcli does not offer this option right now, as you can only tell to which SSID you want to connect to. This could be scripted and used as a cronjob:

```
sudo nmcli device wifi connect "${SSID}" iface "${iface}"
```

Another solution might modify the duration of this annoying gap to a much lower value, but I doubt that this value is configurable right now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Skyo! This is a great analysis, however, there isn't really a "concrete" answer there, so it doesn't solve the question. Have you tried running that `nmcli` command at startup? Did it reduce the gap?

Comment: You are completely right, my answer is incomplete. I could not find any way to reduce the gap, furthermore the gap exist not only during startup but also while switching from one network to another.

However I want to point out, that I believe that there is no way to accomplish this, hence that is the reason for my analysis rather than an "concrete" answer.